# How to resolve: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class com.philips.rs.ui.stepdefs.LoginSteps

Tags: java, exception, junit, constructor, cucumber

I am developing a page object model framework, but I am facing Failed to instantiate class cucumber exception.

Please check my approach

By following this approach I am facing cucumber exception as Failed to instantiate , but this exception will not occur for every first scenario, from second scenario the drive is not launched. Please let me know where I am going wrong

I have @After in ScenarioCleanUp class where webDriver is closed.

```
public class ScenarioCleanUp  {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BrowserTest.class);
    public WebDriver driver = UITestUtils.driver;

    @After()
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---------Closing the Sceanrio-----------------");
        if (scenario.isFailed())
        {
            System.out.println("Came Inside Scenario Failed");
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss");
            Date dateobj = new Date();
            logger.info("CurrentDate used for concating the sceenshot: " + df.format(dateobj));

            logger.error("The Scenario is failed: " + scenario.getName());
            scenario.write("Current Page URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

            String filename = scenario.getName();
            filename = filename.replaceAll("\"", "");
            filename = filename.replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
            filename = filename + df.format(dateobj) + ".jpg";

            new UITestUtils().takeSnapShot(driver,filename);
        }
        if(driver!= null)
        {
        System.out.println("Driver is not null");
        driver.close();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the UITestUtils constructor is called only for the first scenario and also, you are closing the browser in the after scenario. This construction will not be called for the second or more scenarios. There are two solutions,

1. Don't close the browser in the after scenario. or
2. Make the constructor UITestUtils  as method and add it as before hook. So that each time the browser will be open and keep the after scenario hook as it is.